# HTML agility pack first specific childnodes

Tags: filter, nodes, html-agility-pack, child-nodes

```
<html>
<body>
    <p> This 
        <p> should not be displayed twice</p>
    </p>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a> 
    <div> Do not enter</div>
    <p> Gibberish </p>
</body>
</html>
```

So I want to access certain first child nodes of the body-tag. In this case I only want p-tag and a-tag.

Current code:

```
foreach(HtmlNode h in body.Elements("p"))
{
    if (h.Name == "p"){
        //Do something
    }
    if (h.Name == "a"){
       //Do something else
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work since I only get the p-tags from the body-tag. However is there some awesome xpath code that can get me the a-tags aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an "or" (`|`) in your xpath. So you'd come out looking something like this:

```
String xPath = "p|a";
HtmlNodeCollection bodyDecendants = bodyNode.SelectNodes(xPath);
```

Comment: Already tried that. That didn't work. It's like HAP doesn't fully support Xpaths. But apparently it works perfectly with SelectNodes.